# React native flatlist - differentiating between a sent and received message

Tags: react-native

I am currently trying to implement my chat screen, where I am trying to differentiate between received messages and sent messages.

I have created a component called MessageBubble which takes a prop called mine if the message is sent by the current user.

With the implementation below, when I open the chat on 2 different devices they both have the message right (sent by the current user) where one of them is supposed to have it on the left.

here is my flatlist code:

````js
     <FlatList
        inverted
        data={message.Messages}
        keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({item,index})=>(
        message.Messages.map(x=>x.senderId) === user.id?
        <MessageBubble mine text= {item.message} />:<MessageBubble text={item.message} />
        )}
        />
``
user.id ----> is the id of the current user


When i console.log(message.Messages.map(x=>x.senderId)), i get an array with all the senderIds
```react
    Array [
    43,
    43,
    43,
    43,
    ]
````

When I console.log(message.Messages), I get the following:

```js
    Array [
    Object {
    "conversationId": 15,
    "createdAt": "2020-12-14T11:38:41.471Z",
    "id": 54,
    "message": "Hey user1",
    "receiverId": 47,
    "senderId": 43,
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-14T11:38:41.471Z",
    },
    Object {
    "conversationId": 15,
    "createdAt": "2020-12-14T10:28:54.685Z",
    "id": 52,
    "message": "Test12345",
    "receiverId": 47,
    "senderId": 43,
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-14T10:28:54.685Z",
    },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
renderItem={({item,index})=>(
    <MessageBubble 
       text={item.message} 
       mine={item.senderId === user.id} // this way 
    />
)}
```

Comment: Hi Nooruddin, thank you. I wanted to ask are you familiar with socket.io?

Comment: Nops sorry, I don't have any idea

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, did you manage to have a look at my question?

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65325432/react-native-flatlist-does-not-update-instantly-when-i-send-a-message/65339450#65339450

Answer (score 1):

You closed bracket incorrectly. `message.Messages.map(x=>x.senderId) === user.id?` this means that you iterated over the messages array, map returned a new array, and you checked whether this new array is equal to user.id or not which is always false.

Comment: ohh, and that is why clg(message.Messages.map(x=>x.senderId)) keeps returning a new array with just the senderId. I have used @Nooruddin solution above and it worked. Do you agree it is the right approach?

Comment: A quick question, have you used socket.io before?

Comment: Nooruddin's answer is correct as you see. I just indicated your mistake :))

Comment: @kd12345 No, I'm not familiar.

Comment: Ok, thank you, appreciate it :) so map always returns a new array correct?

Comment: Yes. You can check it on your own. `const newArray = [1, 2, 3].map(num => num);` newArray will be [1, 2, 3] array in this case.