# React native: Flatlist does not update instantly when i send a message

Tags: react-native

I just finishing setting up my socket in my react native and nodejs project and still my flatlist does not update instantly when a message is sent, i need to refresh the app in order for it to update.

I thought that by using socket this will work but still it is not working. whenever i user opens a chat i get eg. user: 1 has joined conversation 1 in the console which indicates that the socket is working.

Client Side

```
function ChatScreen({route,navigation}) {
const message = route.params.message;

const [messages, setMessages] = useState(message.Messages);
const [text, setText] = useState('');
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
const { user } = useAuth();

const index = route.params.index;
const updateView = route.params.updateView;

useEffect(() => {
const newsocket =io.connect(socketURL)
setMessages(messages);
newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
    console.log(`user: ${user.id} has joined conversation ${message.id}`)
    setMessages(messages=>messages.concat(msg))
    setSocket(newsocket)
 });
 return()=>newsocket.close;
 }, []);

const onSend = (ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message) => {

messagesApi.sendMessage({ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message});
setText("")

const to = (user.id===route.params.message.user1? 
route.params.message.user2:route.params.message.user1)

socket.emit('message', { to: to, from: user.id, message, ConversationId });
};

const updateText=(text)=>{
setText(text);
}

return (
    <FlatList
    inverted
    data={message.Messages}
    keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({item,index})=>(
        <>
        <Text>
         {moment(item.createdAt).fromNow()}
         </Text>
        <MessageBubble
        text={item.message}
        mine={item.senderId !== user.id}
        />
         </>
    )}      
    />
    <View style={styles.messageBoxContainer}>
        <TextInput 
        onChangeText={updateText} 
        value={text} 
        />
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={()=>{onSend(message.id,user.id,(user.id===message.user1? 
          message.user2:message.user1),text)}}>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
);
}
```

Server Side

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const socket = require("socket.io")
const server=http.createServer(app);
const io =socket(server)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log("connected")
socket.on('message', (data) => {
console.log(data)
  socket.join(data.ConversationId);
  io.sockets.in(data.to).emit('send_message', { message: 
  data.message, to: data.to });
  });
  });
```

### *UPDATE*

Client Side

```
  const message = route.params.message;
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const { user } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
  const newsocket =io.connect("http://192.168.1.103:9000")
  newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
  console.log(`user: ${user.id} has joined conversation 
  ${message.id}`)
  setSocket(newsocket)
  setMessages(message.Messages)
  });

  newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
  console.log("this is the chat message:", msg);
  setMessages([ { ...message.Messages },...messages]);
  });

  return()=>newsocket.close;
  }, []);

  const onSend = (ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message) => {
  console.log("sent")
messagesApi.sendMessage({ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message});
setText("")
const to = (user.id===route.params.message.user1? 
route.params.message.user2:route.params.message.user1)
    socket.emit(
    'message', { to: to, from: user.id, message,ConversationId });
  };

 const updateText=(text)=>{
 setText(text);
 }

<FlatList
    inverted
    data={messages}
    keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({item,index})=>(
        <>
        <Text>
         {moment(item.createdAt).fromNow()}
         </Text>
        <MessageBubble
        text={item.message}
        mine={item.senderId !== user.id}
        />
         </>
    )}   
    bounces={false}  
    />
    <View style={styles.messageBoxContainer}>
        <TextInput 
        onChangeText={updateText} 
        value={text} 
        />
        <TouchableOpacity 
         onPress={()=>{
         onSend(
         message.id,
         user.id, 
         (user.id===message.user1?message.user2:message.user1),
         text
         )}}
         >
         <Text>Send</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
```

Server Side

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log("connected")
socket.on('message', (data) => {
console.log(data)
socket.emit('send_message', { message: data.message, receiverId: 
data.to,senderId:data.from,conversationId:data.ConversationId })
});
});
```

Using the updated code, when i open a chat i get

```
user: 43 has joined conversation 4 ---- on client side console
connected ---- on server side console
```

Using the updated code, when i send a message i get

```
this is the chat message: Object {
"conversationId": 25,
"message": "You",
"receiverId": 47,
"senderId": 43,
} --- in my client side console

{ to: 47, from: 43, message: 'You', ConversationId: 25 } ---- server 
side console
```

But then i get an error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'message.id.toString')
```

I think my problem is that i am not emitting the the message id correctly and therefore my flatlist does not know it. To get a message id, i need to store the message in db first

### *NEW UPDATE*

Client Side

```
  const message = route.params.message;
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const { user } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
  const newsocket =io.connect(socketURL)
  newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
  console.log(`user: ${user.id} has joined conversation 
  ${message.id}`)
  setSocket(newsocket)
  setMessages(message.Messages)
  });

  newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
  console.log("this is the chat message:", msg);
  const data = [...messages]; 
  console.log(data)
  data.push(msg);
  setMessages(data); 
  });

  return(()=>newsocket.close());
  }, []);

  const onSend = (ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message) => {
  console.log("sent")
messagesApi.sendMessage({ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message});
setText("")
const to = (user.id===route.params.message.user1? 
route.params.message.user2:route.params.message.user1)
    socket.emit(
    'message', { to: to, from: user.id, message,ConversationId });
  };

 const updateText=(text)=>{
 setText(text);
 }

<FlatList
    inverted
    data={messages}
    keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
    renderItem={({item,index})=>(
        <>
        <Text>
         {moment(item.createdAt).fromNow()}
         </Text>
        <MessageBubble
        text={item.message}
        mine={item.senderId !== user.id}
        />
         </>
    )}   
    bounces={false}  
    />
    <View style={styles.messageBoxContainer}>
        <TextInput 
        onChangeText={updateText} 
        value={text} 
        />
        <TouchableOpacity 
         onPress={()=>{
         onSend(
         message.id,
         user.id, 
         (user.id===message.user1?message.user2:message.user1),
         text
         )}}
         >
         <Text>Send</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
```

Server Side

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log("connected")
socket.on('message', (data) => {
console.log(data)
socket.emit('send_message', { message: data.message, receiverId: 
data.to,senderId:data.from,conversationId:data.ConversationId })
});
});
```

Now using the new updated code when i send a message only the new message gets rendered to the sender without the previous messages, and the receiver does not receive anything while on the chat.

Comment: The only thing your listening for is a connection, you will want to also listen for messages,.. eg. `newsocket.on('msg', => .....)`  inside this event you can then call `setMessages`,  Your server side will of course need to also emit these new messages.

Comment: @Keith i already have an emitted socket for the messages in my server side, i have added it to the code above

Comment: But you are not listening to the socket updates on the client side, are you? From your code you just listen for the connection on the client. Moreover, you would have to update the state/props with every message that you receive, but right now you intake your data from `message.Messages`, which comes from route.

Comment: @Konstantin in my onSend function in client side i am using socket.emit for the message event

Comment: Emitting is used for sending messages, `socket.on(smth)` is used for receiving socket messages. Where are you receiving them?

Comment: then i have not implemented receiving the new messages

Comment: Please refer to my answer. Also note that in the solution provided you have `socket.on("GroupChat", ...)`, which is the thing that you are missing.

Comment: I thought GroupChat is my connection in this question not my message?

Comment: @kd12345 added info again.

Comment: add your dependency array in useEffect function like this  useEffect(() => {},[setMessages]); or useEffect(() => {},[messages]);

first confirm is message recive from socket (i don’t know much about socket)

Answer (score 0):

So from your answers I get the impression that in order to make it work you would need to do roughly the following:

1. On your client side you gotta have a socket listening for updates:

`socket.on('send_message', (e) => doSomethingWith(e));`

2. Once you have your socket listening to updates, you can treat the information received. The easiest way to make sure your component rerenders and shows the correct information is to use state. So upon receiving the message from the socket, you could set the messages

`setMessages(socketMessage)`

3. You then pass `messages` state to your `data` in Flatlist. I would also pass it in the `extraData` field [also](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) in Flatlist.
   If you have redux in place, you may want to save the messages there, then there will be no need to set the local state in the component and you could just take it from props.

Hope this helps, if you have any additional questions don't hesitate to ask them.

Edit 1:

I'm just gonna copy the code from the solution you mentioned above:

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleGetGroupMessage();
    let socket = io(socketUrl);
    socket.on("GroupChat", (msg) => {
      console.log("this is the chat messages", chatMessages);
      setChatMessages(chatMessages.concat(msg)); // this is the "doSomethingWith(e)"
    });
  }, []);
```

You receive your message via the socket and then have to do something with it. Not using redux? Set it to local state or to top level context, whatever works for your app.

Edit 2:
`socket.on('connect', ...)` is a standard [event](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99) which socket understands. It's not your messages, you need to establish that apart.

Comment: Hi thank you for the more detailed explanation, i am not using redux. What do you mean by doSomethingWith(e)?

Comment: @kd12345 added info to my answer.

Comment: Hi, i have update my code above can you please check if what i did is correct

Comment: I would think the receiving end is correct, you gotta make sure you're receiving the messages. If you do, then you just gotta change the data that you pass to flatlist and you would be good.

Comment: where should i be receiving the messages? i just tried sending a message i did not get 'this is the chat message' in the console. Does this mean my socket is not working in client side?

Comment: Do you receive 'connect' event on client, meaning socket is connected correctly? Do you emit correctly from your server side?

Comment: yes i do, i get this in my terminal when i press on a chat user: 43 has joined conversation 17

Comment: Your variable is named `newsocket`, not `socket`. So it should be `newsocket.on(`send_message`, ...)`. You also don't need to set socket to state, I'm not sure what that gives you tbh.

Comment: Make sure you are emitting correctly. I can't dive into your emits on the server because I haven't worked that much with it, but it's a question of finetuning the emit, your client should be receiving the event normally now. Try emitting something manually and see if you get the event on the client and work from there.

Comment: for every on i need an emit and vice versa?

Comment: You need to emit an event from the server and then listen to the event on the client side. Event name has to be the same.

Comment: can i emit an event on client side and listen on server? like in my onSend function?

Comment: Yes, of course! It's the way of communicating via socket between client and server.
Please refer to this https://socket.io/get-started/chat/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<FlatList
    inverted
    data={messages}
    keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
    extraData={messages} // add this    
    renderItem={({item,index})=>(...)} 


useEffect(() => {
  ...

  newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
    console.log("this is the chat message:", msg);
    // setMessages([ { ...message.Messages },...messages]); // remove this

    // add this 
    const data = [...messages]; 
    data.push(msg);
    setMessages(data);      
  });

  ...
  }, []);
```

Comment: just tried this and got Error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'message.id.toString').

Comment: when i console.log(msg) i get Object {
  "conversationId": 26,
  "message": "Hii",
  "receiverId": 47,
  "senderId": 43,
} which is missing the message because it still needs to get stored in database in order for it to a message id

Comment: update `keyExtractor` like i have updated my answer

Comment: now when i send a message only the new message gets shown not the entire list of messages

Comment: @kd12345 Log data when you spread it and see what's there

Comment: @LeriGogsadze now when i console.log(data) and try sending a message i get Array[] as my response

Comment: @LeriGogsadze Hi Leri, hope you are doing good. Can you please have a look at my update question. I could really use any help possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to update your state like this

socketServcies.on("chatMessageDisplay", (data) => {
            setChatData((prevState) => {
                let newState = [...prevState, data]
                return newState
            })

});


and on the Flatlist side you need to do like this

<FlatList inverted data={[...chatData].reverse()} extraData={chatData} renderItem={({
                        item
                    }) => <Box borderBottomWidth="0.2" _dark={{
                        borderColor: "gray.50"
                    }} borderColor="muted.200" pl={["2", "4"]} pr={["2", "8"]} py="2" >
                            <HStack space={[2, 3]} justifyContent="space-between" >
                                <Avatar size="32px" source={{
                                    uri: item.avatar ? item.avatar : "https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                                }} />
                                <VStack>
                                    <Text _dark={{
                                        color: "warmGray.50"
                                    }} color="coolGray.800" bold>
                                        {item.username}
                                    </Text>
                                    <Text color="coolGray.600" style={{
                                        flexGrow: 1,
                                        flex: 1,
                                    }} _dark={{
                                        color: "coolGray.200",

                                    }} bold>
                                        {item.message}
                                    </Text>
                                </VStack>
                                <Spacer />
    
                            </HStack>
                        </Box>} keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${index}`} />
```

This will work!!!

in the above question

setMessages(messages=>messages.concat(msg))

we are not updating the state with its previous value. messages=> is not the previous value.

instead for example

setChatData((prevState) => {
let newState = [...prevState, data]
return newState
})

previous state value comes in prevState. we need to use the exact keyword

Comment: Can you indicate precisely what in your answer would work for them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The problem is in setting the state. if we apply setChatData((prevState) => {
                let newState = [...prevState, data]
                return newState
            }). we are trying here to set a new value. we should not be doing that instead we should be updating it.